# iOS: keep method working in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My application has a method, which begins its work after the user clicks the button. Method is downloading several files.

How to make so that after the application goes into the background, downloading did not stop and continued?

**Update:** the method.

```
-(void)refreshTable:(id)sender {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self method];
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Only certain kinds of apps are allowed to run in the background indefinitely](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4):

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
  such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as
  a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

If you think your app could use the "`fetch`" background mode, add that to the "`UIBackgroundModes`" key in your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: I'm currently added "fetch" key. But it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: try cleaning your project and/or deleting & reinstalling the app from the device (sometimes updated info.plist files don't get transferred).

Comment: have you implemented background fetch correctly? http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/